# Not able to Load .so file Shared Object File generated from Cython

Tags: python, c, numpy, cython, pypi

I tried running cython compile time optimization on FastAPI serving layer in python during ML Model inferencing.

Instead of loading plain python module for ML Model , I tried loading cython compile ML Module in FastAPI Server.

I am using below code to load generated .so file dynamically in python run time.

```
// load module functionality
loader = ExtensionFileLoader("EnterQueryFastText", "../pipelines/EnterQueryFastText/EnterQueryFastText.cpython-310-darwin.so")
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("EnterQueryFastText",location="../pipelines/EnterQueryFastText/EnterQueryFastText.cpython-310-darwin.so",loader=loader)
your_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["EnterQueryFastText"] = your_module
spec.loader.exec_module(your_module)

// calling method ( pre_process,transform, post_process) in loaded module

input = {"query":"achi"}
pre_proc_output:Any = your_module.pre_process(input)
transform_output:Any = your_module.transform(pre_proc_output)
post_proc_output:Any = your_module.post_process(transform_output)
print(post_proc_output)
```

Error :

```
EnterQueryFastText' has no attribute 'pre_process'
```

Any idea what is going wrong here ?

FYI -

adding cython class structure for reference

```
cdef class EnterQueryFastText:

  cpdef transform(self, payload):

    cdef embedding = self._get_sentence_vector(payload)
    return embedding

  cpdef pre_process(self, input: dict):

    cdef pre_processed_input = cleanText(input['query'])
    return pre_processed_input
```

tried googling other options available for loading cython (.so file) module but could not find any better mechanism

Comment: Isn't the module also called `EnterQueryFastText`. And you're looking up the attribute from the module rather than the class

Comment: yes module is also 'EnterQueryFastText' . Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I think doing `print(dir(your_module))` would probably clear things up. The point is: the methods you've defined are methods of a class, but you're trying to call them on the module instead.